# Respecting Header Height

Tags: css, css-float

I need help aligning my fixed widget and floating navigation. Currently the fixed widget does not respect the height of my floating navigation and aligns top when in its fixed position. I am currently using "Q2W3 Fixed Widget" for my sidebar widget and CSS to "float" the navigation.

I would like the fixed widget to align bottom of the nav and not have half of the text get hidden behind the nav.

If you need to see a live page demonstration/code, here is an [example](https://www.shiftins.com/blog/boat-insurance-5-things-remember-want-perfect-policy/). Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was looking at the faq at https://wordpress.org/plugins/q2w3-fixed-widget/faq/. You can set a bottom and top margin as explained in the following section:

> **How to prevent overlapping with the footer?**
>
> Make sure you have updated plugin to version 2.x. Go to WP admin area, Appearance -> Fixed Widget Options. Here you can define top and bottom margins. Set bottom margin value >= footer height. Check the result.